# Either....and...or? Either...or...or?

Tags: either-or

"Use the installation wizard to choose between either a and b, or to install both of them simultaneously."
or is it
"Use the installation wizard to choose between either a or b, or to install both of them simultaneously."

Also, is there a comma before the second or, am I omitting any other comma(s), is it grammatically correct to have such a structure even, should I restructure it ;0

Comment: Yes, you should restructure it. Even just changing the formatting (visual layout) can help.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence! Do you think it works like that: 'Use the installation wizard to choose between a, b, or their simultaneous installation.'

Comment: Re-reading your question, I'm now unsure what difference you're drawing between "a and b" and "both of them".

Comment: If you actually have 3 options, just say "a, b, or both". Or even "a or b or both".

Comment: If you use the word *between*, then *and* is used. *You choose* ***between*** *one thing* ***and*** *another.* If you remove *between*, then you use *or*. *You choose one thing* ***or*** *another.*

Answer (score 1):

**"Choose either A and B, or C"** means, in general, two choices:

- **A and B**
- **C**

**"Choose either A or B, or C"** means, in general, three choices:

- **A**
- **B**
- **C**

If **"C"** is equivalent to **"A and B"**,
**"Choose either A and B, or C"** gives no choice at all: it always means **"A and B"**.
**"Choose either A or B, or C"** in this case means three choices:

- **A**
- **B**
- **A and B**

And, in any case, the word **"between"** is superfluous in this construction.